# How to fill in a "jagged" list?

Tags: python, list

I have the following "jagged" python list:

```
lst = [[1, 'a', 2], ['b', 'c', 'd', 3, 4, 5], ['e']]
```

I would like to fill in "missing" values in this list with 0, so that the result is the rectangular array:

```
[[1, 'a', 2, 0, 0, 0],
 ['b', 'c', 'd', 3, 4, 5],
 ['e', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It might be too much gun for your problem but [awkward-array](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-array) can handle jagged structures efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.zip_longest`, then re-zip the result

```
>>> lst = [[1, 'a', 2], ['b', 'c', 'd', 3, 4, 5], ['e']]
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=0))]
[[1, 'a', 2, 0, 0, 0], ['b', 'c', 'd', 3, 4, 5], ['e', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

`zip(*t)` is a well-known idiom for transposing a list of lists; the same trick works with `zip_longest`. Since the transpose of a transpose is the original list, this pads each sublist to the desired length.

---

In more detail,

```
>>> list(zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=0))
[(1, 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 0), (2, 'd', 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 4, 0), (0, 5, 0)]
```

Here you can see the tuple of first elements, followed by the tuple of second elements, etc. `0` is used when there is no `i`th element in a given sublist.